# GoogleTest - Read log while test is running

Tags: googletest

Im trying to write a test in GoogleTest that will execute some code, and it will pass or not depending on the output logs caused by that code.
For that, I would like to have access to the test log, but I have not found how to do it.

While the test is running, this `Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log.tmp` file exists but it only contains the start date:

```
Start testing: Oct 01 13:10 CEST
----------------------------------------------------------
```

So it seems the logs are not written there until the test ends, and `Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log` is created.

Is there a way to read the test logs before the test ends?

Comment: What do you mean with "test log"? Google Test does not write any logs, except for the test results. If the log is written by your own code under test, you have to look there. For example, can you redirect logging or flush logging?

Comment: Also, looking at the logging is not the best way to check whether your code works as expected. You should probably redesign your code to make it testable.